# Advice on cleaner way to write this While statement

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

So the following code works, it is doing everything i want it to do. However, as i step back it seems like an overly convoluted approach to what is arguably one of the most common tasks in php.

I know enough about php to figure out what most things are doing when i see them, and to create some rather ugly code like you will see below; however, the finer points evade me.

I was hoping that if someone had some free time, he/she could look this over and show me a more concise way to approach this.

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events'); 
$i = 1; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<div id="item_gallery_s'.$i .'"'. 'class="fluid profileImgWrap goldDiagGrad">' .
         '<div class="profile_name">' . $row['name'] . '<br /><span class="profile_date">' .
         '<a href="http:#" 
             target="_blank"
             title="some title">' . $row['place'] . 
         '</a></span></div><!-- DCD Diva Name -->' .

         '<a rel="events[events]" 
             href="#">' .
         '<div class="profile_banner">Custom Banner</div><!-- Banner -->' .
         '<img src='.'"img/upload/'.$row['icon']. 
         '"' . 
         'alt="image description |'.$row['name']. 
         '"/>' . 
         '<!-- Photo --></a></div><!-- END #item_gallery_s'.$i .'-->';

        $i++;   
}?>
```

Comment: More concise in what way? There's no easier way to loop but you could likely use some sort of html template or php/html output to have cleaner html markup. I personally dislike wrapping html in a bunch of echo statements.

Comment: "More concise in what way?" I don't know, i just figured there must be a better option than all of the quotes and concatenation used in my method. I tried and failed with a foreach loop which looks a bit cleaner when i see it else where.

Comment: Hmm. I would say that wrapping HTML in echoes is (in this case) preferable to constantly hopping in and out of PHP mode with `<?php ... ?>` tags. If you just have an occasional PHP statement, having it mostly HTML might be better -- it's a matter of judgement. One thing I _would_ do is consolidate tags spread across lines: `'<a rel="events[events]" href="#">' .`, `'<img src="img/upload/'.$row['icon'].'"' .` etc. Note that you can have `echo '`, multiple HTML lines, and end with `';`. It would be a bit neater with fewer quotes and concatenations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop itself is fine but you'll find varying opinions on the HTML-in-strings. For the past seven years I've encouraged my team to either use HTML with php tags or we rely on a full templating system:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <div><?= $row['something'] ?></div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Though we have short tags enabled for even cleaner code. The benefit of this is that it's cleaner - less quotes, escaping problems, and IDEs will be able to syntax highlight the html. Most treat the html as string when it's inside quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciated. Im going to go ahead and look into Smarty since every respondent references a template engine.

Comment: twig might be better. Last I heard, smarty was pretty outdated.

Answer (score 0):

That's as "concise" as it gets.

You could not use an echo inside the while. And use php short tags.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<a href="http:#" target="_blank" title="some title"><?=$row['place'];?></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Another way to "clean up", would be to use a template engine, but once again that would be just for the HTML part.

```
<a href="http:#" target="_blank" title="some title">{place}</a>
```

Good coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up a bit by interspersing actual HTML, rather than simply echoing it:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events'); 
$i = 1; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<div id="item_gallery_s<?php echo $i; ?>" class="fluid profileImgWrap goldDiagGrad">
    <div class="profile_name">
        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
        <br />
        <span class="profile_date"><a href="http:#" target="_blank" title="some title"><?php echo $row['place']; ?></a></span>
    </div><!-- DCD Diva Name -->
    <a rel="events[events]" href="#"><div class="profile_banner">Custom Banner</div><!-- Banner -->
    <img src="img/upload/<?php echo $row['icon']; ?>" alt="image description |<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"/><!-- Photo --></a>
</div><!-- END #item_gallery_s<?php echo $i; ?> -->
<?php
    $i++;   
}?>
```

Another option, depending on how much work like this you have to do, would be a full-blown template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: @AndréCatita, Indeed, I was just a bit slower typing!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would probably format this code (as a matter of personal style):

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events'); 
$i = 1; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo 
   '<div id="item_gallery_s'.$i.'" class="fluid profileImgWrap goldDiagGrad">
     <div class="profile_name">' . $row['name'] . '<br /><span class="profile_date">
       <a href="http:#" target="_blank" title="some title">' . $row['place'] . 
       '</a></span>
     </div><!-- DCD Diva Name -->

     <a rel="events[events]" href="#">
       <div class="profile_banner">Custom Banner</div><!-- Banner -->
       <img src="img/upload/' . $row['icon']. '" 
          alt="image description |' . $row['name']. '"/> 
          <!-- Photo -->
     </a>
   </div><!-- END #item_gallery_s'.$i .'-->';

   $i++;   
}
?>
```

Try also to use consistent indentation to make it easy to tell what matches up with what. By the way, a `<div>` (block element) inside an `<a>` (inline element) is bad form. Did you mean to use a `<span>`? Learn to use the W3C validator to pick up this stuff.

Comment: yea, its going to be a span tag. The anchor was added after i had finished the block, at which point i began to obsess over the coding itself. Good catch though.